# C++ read text file into array, run error: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read a text file into 3D array. The compile goes well, but I got running error: "segmentation fault". Anybody has suggestions?
Thank you!

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
  const int x =  288;
  const int y =  288;
  const int z = 30;

  float realimg[x][y][z];
  Array<std::complex<float>,3> realimage(x,y,z);
  Array<std::complex<float>,3> imagimage(x,y,z); 
    ifstream fin1("realfile.txt");
  for ( int kk = 0; kk < z; ++kk )
  {
    for ( int jj = 0; jj < y; ++jj )
    { 
      for ( int ii = 0; ii < x; ++ii )
      {
        fin1 >>realimg[ii][jj][kk];
        realimage(ii,jj,kk)=realimg[ii][jj][kk];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possibly a error in `class Array` - which is where all the actual work is done and we can't see it.  Also test if `fin1 >> ...` is true before working with the result.

Comment: 288*288*30*sizeof(float) = 9953280 bytes (close to 10MB) on the stack. You might be reaching (and passing) the maximum stack size.

Comment: You should be able to use a debugger to find out exactly what line is causing the segmentation fault.  And where the source for the Array class?

Answer (score 1):

```
  const int x =  288;
  const int y =  288;
  const int z = 30;

  float realimg[x][y][z];
```

This allocates `realimg` array on stack. The size of this array is `288*288*30*sizeof(float) == 9953280 bytes == 9.5MiB`. On a typical Linux system, default stack size is `8MiB`.

If the crash goes away after you do `ulimit -s unlimited`, then stack exhaustion is indeed your problem. One possible solution is to allocate `readlimg` on the heap (using `malloc`) instead.